# Select new users from a specific month

Tags: powerbi, daxstudio

I have a table with a column Users and LogInDate.
I need to find all user that that created an account 8 months ago from today.
For exemple, today is dec/28/2021 and i need to find new users from April/2021.

I could do that in sql to retrive date

```
SELECT CURRENT_DATE
      ,TRUNC(ADD_MONTHS(CURRENT_DATE,-8),'MM') AS   FROM
      ,LAST_DAY(ADD_MONTHS(CURRENT_DATE,-8))   AS   TO
 FROM DUAL;
```

but the problem is that I can't figure out how to do that in Power BI.

Could you please help me out?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can use in your DAX query filter based on:

```
  'SomeTable'[CreateDate] >= DATE(YEAR(TODAY()),MONTH(TODAY())-8, 1)



EVALUATE
{TODAY(),
 DATE(YEAR(TODAY()),MONTH(TODAY())-8, 1),
 DATE(YEAR(TODAY()),MONTH(TODAY())-20, 1)
}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks, you helped me a lot.
Cheers.